# IIS-like UI for http.sys programs

Tags: iis, configuration-management

Does anyone know if there is a open-source or built-in way to view ALL IIS and http.sys endpoints/sites via a GUI?

The problem I have is that I'm a little wary of having no visibility for http.sys applications (e.g. SQL Reporting Services 2008) and their status, logs, security settings, etc.  I know there is documentation how to do this via command line and registry hacks but it seems there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HTTP Server API Configuration](http://httpsysmanager.codeplex.com/), is a GUI tool that lists endpoints and allows you to set ACLs. The author 'Nicolas Dorier' also has a nice article 'Demystify http.sys with HttpSysManager' on [CodeProject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/437733/Demystify-http-sys-with-HttpSysManager) which describes his tool.

Answer (score -3):

I hope this command can help you.

```
netsh http show urlacl
```

Comment: You don't like reading, right? Which part of "UI" or "GUI" is not clear? A command line tool does not qualify as answer.